# How does the static port on an airplane accurately measure ambient pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Some background: The standard altimeter in an airplane works by measuring the outside atmospheric pressure, corrected for local weather. It does this through a "static port", a little hole on the outside of the plane, oriented 90 degrees to the airstream, that's connected to the altimeter (and other instruments) with a simple tube.

The problem is that planes tend to move fairly fast. So, wouldn't the Venturi effect cause the pressure read by the altimeter to go down the faster the plane went?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the location of the static port on an airplane's fuselage is carefully chosen so that at that spot, the venturi effect is cancelled by other effects and the pressure that is measured at that point is almost exactly equal to the static pressure.

A standard joke among do-it-yourself aircraft builders is that it is easy to get a plane to fly 200MPH on 100HP if you are allowed to put the static port anywhere you want- which is another way of saying that a misplaced static port will not read static pressure accurately!

Comment: "the location of the static port on an airplane's fuselage is carefully chosen so that at that spot, the venturi effect is cancelled by other effects..." Is the spot chosen to cancel venturi effects, or is it simply chosen to be perpendicular to air stream (to avoid measuring any part of dynamic pressure)? Given that the hole is oriented perpendicular to an otherwise unconfined atmospheric air stream, will there necessarily be venturi effects?

Comment: I have never performed the exercise, so I do not know- suggest you try migrating this question to the aviation stack exchange, lots of experts there.